# Why can I not retrieve custom classes from cloudmine, android app?

Tags: android

I have stored a custom cloudmine object class in the cloudmine database. However, when I try to retrieve it,nothing is happening. It is not retriving. even though on the cloudmine dashboard, it keeps saying object retrieved, everytime the app is run. Here is my code for the  activity where it is not getting the objects.

```
package com.android.nest;

import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.cloudmine.api.CMApiCredentials;
import com.cloudmine.api.CMObject;
import com.cloudmine.api.rest.CMStore;
import com.cloudmine.api.rest.callbacks.CMObjectResponseCallback;
import com.cloudmine.api.rest.response.CMObjectResponse;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ScheduleActivity extends Activity 
{
// Find this in your developer console
private static final String APP_ID = "********";
// Find this in your developer console
private static final String API_KEY = "*******";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);

     CMApiCredentials.initialize(APP_ID, API_KEY, getApplicationContext());
      CMStore store = CMStore.getStore();


      store.loadApplicationObjectsOfClass(MyObject.CLASS_NAME, new CMObjectResponseCallback() 
      {
            public void onCompletion(CMObjectResponse response) 
            {
                System.out.println("onCompletion Method");
                for(CMObject object : response.getObjects())
                {
                    System.out.println("inside for loop");
                       MyObject tempObject = (MyObject) object;
                       Toast.makeText(ScheduleActivity.this, "getting cloudmine object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
            }
        });

}
}
```

Here is how I register the class:

```
static{

    try
    {
        ClassNameRegistry.register(MyObject.CLASS_NAME, MyObject.class);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overriding the class name, so you need to call `ClassNameRegistry.register()` and pass in the `CLASS_NAME` and the class, before loading the object by its class.

Comment: I already have it registered in the main activity  like the following

Comment: static {
    
  try
  {
   ClassNameRegistry.register(MyObject.CLASS_NAME, MyObject.class);
  }catch(Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: For some reason, Cloudmine does not like Hashtmaps but with hashtable everything worked! However, there were some major problems with casting objects back from parent to child, no idea why, so I just had to combine in to one class.

Answer (score 0):

CloudMine should handle HashMaps fine - can you post the MyObject code? Also, what problems did you have with parent vs child objects? That should work fine as long as you overrode getClassName in the child class to give it a different name as the parent - or didn't override either of them.